# How to prevent ComboBox SelectionChangedEvent from firing when using keyboard arrow keys?

Tags: c#

I have a ComboBox that's populated with a number of items.

I've specified a `SelectionChangedEvent` as follows:

```
cbo.SelectionChangedEvent += (s, e) => DoSelectionChangedThing();
```

This works well enough when I click an item in the ComboBox; `DoSelectionChangedThing()` runs as expected.

The problem is that if I use the arrow up or down keys to cycle through the items, each time I arrow up or down `DoSelectionChangedThing()` fires.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: If you inspect the event getting passed into `DoSelectionChangedThing()` you could probably tell if it was a keypress and abort. A fiddle would help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [dropdownclosed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.dropdownclosed(v=vs.110).aspx) event instead of SelectionChangedEvent.

> Occurs when the drop-down list of the combo box closes.

Comment: and what if the user uses the mouse to scroll? The index would still get changed through the mouse and not raise the above event

Comment: requires .NET Framework 4.5, unfortunately. This solution is 4.0.

Comment: @DaveDev, DropDownClosed is in .NET 3 to 4.5

Comment: Well I'll be.. I'll investigate.

Comment: The arrow keys trigger selection when the dropdown is opened. There's nothing to do with the dropdownclosed.

Answer (score 0):

Capture the arrow keys on that box and disable the selection using `return true`.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.Down && comboBox1.Focused)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

If you want to open the dropdown and select an item, use `return false` after opening.